# internal error in outgoing dependency subsystem flash builder - Air 3.9

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I have upgraded flex builder to 4.7 (from 4.6) and installed air 3.9.

when creating a project (as3 mobile) and embedding an image I get the following error:

internal error in outgoing dependency subsystem flash builder

I saw this bug from last year : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33415

I hope that someone managed to embed images with air 3.9 and can share a solution to this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: When you say you installed AIR 3.9; do you mean you are using Apache Flex 4.11 with the AIR 3.9 SDK?  Or did you just install the AIR 3.9 runtime on your machine?

Comment: I have copied the new AIR_SDK_3.9 to /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722 as described here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html   , the project is ActionScript-Mobile . Thx

Comment: In that case; I have removed the Flex tag from this question. No parts of the Flex SDK are used in an ActionScript mobile project on Flash Builder 4.7.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue by redoing the process as described here http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html   , 2 things i did differently , not sure what caused the issue :

1. skipped step # 4 on the above link help-docs 
   (Applicable only for AIR versions earlier than 3.6) Copy the contents from the aot folder (AIRSDK_back_up\lib\aot) of the AIR SDK backup to the aot folder of the newly created AIR SDK (AIRSDK\lib\aot).
2. used the command line
       tar jxvf AIRSDK_Compiler.tbz2  instead of unzipping from Finder